# C# web API property object as string not object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have an web API function that has a property that can take different shapes. Actually i need to save a json in database.
I will give you some examples
post body

```
{
    "title":"example 1",
    "type": "0",
    "extraData": { "name": "bob", 
        // here is the catch this is first type of object let's say children
        [{
            "age": 10
            "toys": "bear, goat"
        },
        {
            "age": 18
            "toys": "guitar"
        }]
    }
}   
{
    "title":"example 1",
    "type": "1",
    "extraData": { "name": "john", 
        // here is the catch this is first type of object let's say grandparents
        [{
            "age": 90
            "cars": "honda civic"
        },
        {
            "age": 18
            "car": "renault megan, pegeout 206"
        }]
    }
}
```

Now let's assume that we can't merge grandparents and children together in a class so my classes will look something like:

```
public class Family{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string ExtraData {get; set;}
    public int Type {get;set;}
}
public class ExtraData<T> where T: Person{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<T> Persons {get;set;}
}

public class Person{
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Child : Person{
    public string Toys{get;set;}    
}

public class Grandparent : Person{
    public string Cars{get;set;}    
}
```

In the api method I was thinking to do something like:

```
public void Save(Family model)
{
   // to parse extraData my idea was to
   switch(mode.Type)
   {
    case 0: var childrens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtraData<Child>>(model.ExtraData);
        // do stuff 
       break;
     case 1: var grandparents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtraData<Child>>(model.ExtraData);
        // do stuff 
       break;
   }
  // save the object
}
```

The issue is that on the api call I get nothing in the extraData string. And I can't put in Family something like

```
  public ExtraData<Person> Persons {get;set;}
```

because it will deserialize to the base type and I will lose the subclass information.

I know is to do something like json stringify but I would like this to be my last resort. Also i have tried to use dynamic instead of Family but I still need to deserialze it and having same issue.

What is the best approach here?

Comment: Are you able to change the input?

Comment: Also how can you tell if someone is a child or a grandparent? Both the car and the age key are used abrtrarily it seems

Comment: @Glabus you can tell the type from type property in the family. if the type is 0 you will get only children in list grandparents if type is 1